# How to show JSON data in angular version 2.4.10

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to show json data by Angular. But it is showing entire json data instead particular one.

**Case 1 :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from 'app/http.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http/src/static_response';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-httpapp',
  template: `
    <p>
      httpapp Works!
      <br><hr>
        {{t_obj | json}}
    </p>


    <div *ngFor="let t of t_obj">
        {{t.tname}}//not working
        {{t}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class HttpappComponent implements OnInit {

  t_obj : T ;

  constructor(private httpService : HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.httpService.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (data : Response) => {
        this.setData(data)
      }
    );
  }



  setData(response : Response)
  {
      this.t_obj = response.json();
      console.log(response.json());

  }
}//class

class T{
  tname : string;
}
```

output:

```
[ { "t": "A" }, { "t": "B" }, { "t": "C" } ]

[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

{{t.tname}}, this fragment of code showing nothing.

Below is my server side code :

```
@RestController
public class NewClass
    {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public List greeting()
        {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(new T("A"));
        l.add(new T("B"));
        l.add(new T("C"));
        return l;
        }

    }//public class NewClass

class T
{
    public String t;

    public T(String t)
        {
        this.t = t;
        }

}
```

Now i want to know that how can i show only data instead of the full json object.

**Case 2 :**

Below is my REST controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public T greeting()
    {
    return new T("Done..!");
    }
```

Angular code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-httpapp',
  template: `
    <p>
      httpapp Works!
      <br><hr>
      {{t_obj.t}}
    </p>
  `,
})
export class HttpappComponent implements OnInit {

  t_obj : any ;

  constructor(private httpService : HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.httpService.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (data : Response) => {
        this.setData(data)
      }
    );
  }

  setData(response : Response)
  {
      this.t_obj = response.json();
      console.log(response.json());
      console.log(this.t_obj.t);

  }
}//class
```

For case two i am getting the below error message :

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./HttpappComponent class HttpappComponent - inline template:3:14 caused by: Cannot read property 't' of undefined
Error: Error in ./HttpappComponent class HttpappComponent - inline template:3:14 caused by: Cannot read property 't' of undefined
```

After showing this error message it is printing the below lines :

```
{t: "Done..!"}
 Done..!
```

So my question is, according to the error message if 't' is undefined then how it is being printed in console log.

**Update :**  I got solution for case 1, i have to use {{t.t}}

Comment: which specific verion of angular?

Comment: as per your code, I think it should be {{ t.t}}

Comment: my angular version is 2.4.10

Comment: Check browser console if you are getting any errors. t.tname will not work because from the service the data you are returning,there is no key called tname. Try with t.t .It will work.

Comment: yes it is working. with t.t. so what is the exact reason?

Comment: First t represents the object, and as you can see in [ { "t": "A" }, { "t": "B" }, { "t": "C" } ], so it has {"t": "A"} in the first iteration, so in order to access "A" from this object, you have to use .t on the first t, thus=> t.t

Answer (score 2):

as per your code, it should be {{t.t}}, not {{t.tname}}